# wh-questions about a subject

Tags: grammar, wh-questions

Can we use the stem (not the third-person singular) to form wh-questions about the subject? if the answer given is **hunters** kill animals and were asked to form a question do we say who kill animals? or who kills animals?

Comment: Related question (Who have/has come?): https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22900/on-the-singular-vs-plural-aspects-of-who

Answer (score -1):

You can use either the singular or the plural depending on who you have in mind.

If, for example, you thought that the answer might be **the clans of Somalia** you would probably ask: **Who (are the people who) kill animals.

But if you had an individual (or even a class of individuals in mind) you would probably ask **Who kills animals**.

In the example you give, the answer depends of whether you consider hunters as numerous individuals or a single group.

Comment: So you're saying "Who kill animals?" sounds right to you? It doesn't sound right to me as a native speaker of AmE. (I can't think of a single example of a verb that would sound right in this context in the plural besides *to be*.) Can you provide a source that backs up this information?

Comment: @Laurel Take a classroom situation. A teacher tells pupils:*The fact is that American hunters kill thousands of animals*. Question: *Who kill animals?* Answer: *American hunters kill animals*. Alternatively, change **kill** to **shoot**. *Who shoot animals?* Answer: *Hunters shoot animals?* *Who* can take a singular or plural verb. *Who are (the people) coming through the gate?